# How to GROUP BY one column and ORDER BY another in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have a table of items with some values, among them cost and purchase date. I'm trying to get a list of the most expensive items, one per item type, ordered by the purchase date of that specific item, *without* the purchase date in the results.

My table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE Purchases
    (ItemType varchar(25),
    Cost int,
    PurchaseDate smalldatetime)
```

My sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Purchases VALUES
    ('Hat',     0,      '2007-05-20 15:22'),
    ('Hat',     0,      '2007-07-01 15:00'),
    ('Shirt',   3500,   '2007-07-30 08:43'),
    ('Pants',   2000,   '2008-07-30 12:00'),
    ('Pants',   4000,   '2009-03-15 07:30'),
    ('Sweater', 3000,   '2011-05-20 15:22'),
    ('Sweater', 3750,   '2012-07-01 22:00'),
    ('Sweater', 2700,   '2014-06-12 11:00'),
    ('Hat',     4700,   '2015-06-29 07:10')
```

My expected output (dates added for clarity):

```
ItemType                MostExpensivePerType
------------------------- --------------------
Shirt                     3500                (2007-07-30 08:43)
Pants                     4000                (2009-03-15 07:30)
Sweater                   3750                (2012-07-01 22:00)
Hat                       4700                (2015-06-29 07:10)
```

My work so far:

I've tried things back and forth, and my best result is with this query:

```
SELECT 
    ItemType, MAX(Cost) AS MostExpensivePerType 
FROM 
    Purchases 
GROUP BY 
    ItemType 
ORDER BY 
    MostExpensivePerType DESC
```

Which yields the most expensive items per item type, but orders them by cost. Without the `ORDER BY` clause, they seem to be ordered alphabetically. I realize that I need the date column in my query as well, but can I enter it and 'hide' it in the results? Or do I need to save the results I have so far in a temporary table and join with my regular table? What is the best way to go about this?

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9668a/3/0)!

Comment: I liked the way you added your input data and desired output to the question.. But I couldn't understand your question completely. What do you want in final output?

Comment: I wanted a list of the most expensive items in each category: most expensive hat, shirt, etc. (one of each), but I wanted the list sorted on the dates I bought them. So even if the most expensive hat was more expensive than the most expensive shirt, if the shirt was bought before the hat, the shirt should be listed first. See Mark Bannister's answer :)

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that I misunderstood the question - I thought you wanted it sorted by the most recent purchase of *any* item in the category, but I now realise you want it ordered by the purchase date of the *most expensive item* in the category. I recommend unaccepting my answer and accepting Gordon's answer instead.

Comment: Okay, I've unaccepted  your answer. Gordon's answer doesn't work for me, but i'm sure we'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select ItemType, Cost MostExpensivePerType
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemtype order by cost desc) as seqnum
      from purchases p
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by PurchaseDate;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9668a/38).

Comment: This might be me doing something wrong, but i get these errors: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
The multi-part identifier "p.ItemType" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'MostExpensivePerType'.

Comment: @Tobbe: I've updated Gordon's answer to fix that issue, and added a SQLFiddle link.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
  ItemType, 
  MAX(Cost) AS MostExpensivePerType
FROM 
  Purchases 
GROUP BY 
  ItemType 
ORDER BY
  Max(PurchaseDate) DESC
```

Comment: Might be my database software, but I get this error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Tobbe you're probably using the snippet in a different context (a view/subquery/CTE/..)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.ItemType,a.MostExpensivePerType 
FROM (
  SELECT ItemType, MAX(Cost) AS MostExpensivePerType , MAX(PurchaseDate) AS MaxPurchaseDate 
  FROM Purchases 
  GROUP BY ItemType
  ) a
  ORDER BY a.MaxPurchaseDate DESC
```